# Impossible to pass UIImage between 2 view controllers (without storyboard)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

In the first ViewController (AViewController), I set the camera. When the picture is captured, I present an other ViewController (BViewController) which contains a UIImageView. The problem is the UIImageView in BViewController doesn’t show the picture captured in AViewController. I specify that I don’t use storyboard.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this fail ? Did I miss something ? Thanks for you help!

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {

  ...

  func capture(){

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
        if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
             let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
             let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
             let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

             let imageSaved = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

             self.present(BViewController(), animated: false, completion: { Void in   
                BViewController().integrate(image: imageSaved)
             })                
        }            
    }
  }
}
```

================================================================

```
class BViewController : UIViewController {

   let imageView = UIImageView()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.frame = view.bounds
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)

   }

   func integrate(image: UIImage){
        imageView.image = image
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.present(BViewController(), animated: false, completion: { Void in   
    BViewController().integrate(image: imageSaved)
})
```

The phrase `BViewController()` means "make a completely new view controller". But you say it twice! So the view controller you present (first line) and the view controller you give the image to (second line) are two completely different view controllers.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! I fixed it and posted my solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed it with matt's help :

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {

   func capture(){
      ...
      let destinationVC = BViewController()
      destinationVC.image = imageSaved
      self.present(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
}

//=====================================================

class BViewController : UIViewController {

   var image = UIImage()
   let imageView = UIImageView()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      imageView.frame = view.bounds
      imageView.image = image
      imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
      imageView.clipsToBounds = true
      view.addSubview(imageView)

   }
}
```